# What allows me to write $1$ as $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ (to turn $\int 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$ into $\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}}dx$)?

Tags: calculus, integration

If I have a Riemann integral what is the rule that allows me to rewrite this: \begin{equation} \int 1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}dx\end{equation}
as
\begin{equation}\int \frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}}dx \end{equation}

This is an arbitrary integral.

What allows me to rewrite $1$ as $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$, is it due the limit? Is there a math theorem that allows me to do this procedure in the integral?
Because intuition tells me that if \begin{equation}f(x)=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \end{equation} is different then \begin{equation}g(x)=\frac{\sqrt{x}+1}{\sqrt{x}}\end{equation}

I would also like to note this is not a homework question, just something my mathematics professor has made me curious about.

I have been doing some research on  my own plotting functions and observing discontinuities. If the discontinuity is accounted for in the denominator then I can rewrite the constant term I adding as $x$ over $x$.

Comment: No, it’s simply that $\frac{a}a=1$ for any non-zero real number $a$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott This are functions though that can have discontinuities?

Comment: Aren't domains and ranges important for integrals?

Comment: The original integrand has a denominator $\sqrt{x}$, so we already know that we’re integrating over positive reals.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Yes I understand that part but is there not exception? Lets say that integral is arbitary buts its any integral and I have this constant I want to rewrite as a variable x to power or whatever transform like sin(x) over sin(x).

Comment: You can ignore any single point (or discrete collection of points) in the domain of integration; no matter how you define the function at points where you have $0/0$, if these points are isolated they don't contribute to the area under the curve.

Comment: Put simply, BrianM.Scott's assertion is true anywhere the integral makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in worrying (if only for a moment) that they may not be the same. As you noted, $\dfrac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x-1}$ and $x+1$ are not the same function because they have different domains (hence how we get lines with holes!). But they are the same function for their common domain (the set of real numbers that are not $1$).

There are two ways of thinking to alleviate your concerns. First, observe that $1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and $\dfrac{1+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}}$ have the same domain. Since we multiplied by $1$ (in the form $\sqrt{x}/\sqrt{x}$), they are the same function (same domain and function values everywhere).

Alternatively, by writing
$$
\int \left(1+\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x}} \right)\;dt
$$
You would be assuming you are only integrating this for values of $x$ that 'make sense', even if it's not immediately obvious which those are. Here, we need $\sqrt{x}$ to be defined, so we would assume over the positive reals. But this is the same as the domain for
$$
\int \dfrac{1+\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x}} \;dx
$$
and the integrands are algebraically equivalent over this implied domain.

The former reasoning is really better, but they get you to the same conclusion.